# Read Docker secret in docker-entrypoint

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I can't read my Docker secrets trough my `docker-entrypoint` script. I added all my secrets in my `docker service create` command and each time my service crashing telling me the `/run/secrets/<secret_name>` is not existing.

Someone can tell me why ? And how I can read my secret ?

My docker_entrypoint :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

cp /run/secrets/configuration.py /opt/netbox/netbox/netbox/configuration.py
chmod +x /opt/netbox/netbox/netbox/configuration.py

DJANGO_USER="$(< /run/secrets/django_user)"
DJANGO_MAIL="$(< /run/secrets/django_mail)"
DJANGO_PASS="$(< /run/secrets/django_pass)"

cd /opt/netbox/netbox/
python3.6 manage.py migrate

echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('$DJANGO_USER', '$DJANGO_MAIL', '$DJANGO_PASS')" | python3.6 manage.py shell

python3.6 manage.py collectstatic --noinput

unset DJANGO_USER
unset DJANGO_MAIL
unset DJANGO_PASS

exec "$@"
```

The error:

```
/opt/netbox/entrypoint.sh: line 5: /run/secrets/configuration.py: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error simply states that there is no `/run/secrets/configuration.py` file. Maybe you forgot to add it to your container?

Comment: @lependu No it is, Because when I start my container without the entrypoint. I can read ̀/run/secrets/configuration.py` file.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us how do you run your container without entrypoint?

Comment: do a `ls /run/secrets/` to see if there is anything inside.